# How do I create a line break before the image of a PayPal button?

Tags: button, paypal, line, break, paragraph

So, I've already tried p and br tags, but for some reason nothing changed. How do I create a paragraph after the options? So the image jumps to the next line...
I'm very lay at coding, anyone could help me?
Here's the code I'm using:

```html
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="4G3U9LF2TYKBS">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Style">Style</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os0">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Color">Color</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os1">
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Size">Size</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os2">
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
    <option value="2XL">2XL</option>
    </select>
    </td>   
    <td> 
    <input type="image" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/537a5c42e4b0f3418c1f0939/t/54f0fac5e4b0c3d27ffb863e/1425078981013/Add+to+cart+01B.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: By not placing the image in a `<td>` on the same `<tr>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look in the link [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8ojepse/)

you need to have separate tr for the paypal button

```html
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="4G3U9LF2TYKBS">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Style">Style</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os0">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Color">Color</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os1">
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Size">Size</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os2">
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
    <option value="2XL">2XL</option>
    </select>
    </td>   
         </tr>
        <tr>
    <td> 
        <input type="image" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/537a5c42e4b0f3418c1f0939/t/54f0fac5e4b0c3d27ffb863e/1425078981013/Add+to+cart+01B.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
    </td> 
</tr> 
</table>
</form>
```